# nodejs .exe app crashed immediately opened in UWP

Tags: node.js, process, uwp

First, sorry for my poor English. I want to call .exe app in order to run a javascript in UWP, and I'm using FullTrustProcessLauncher. The extension I set is as below.

```html
<Extensions>
        <desktop:Extension Category="windows.fullTrustProcess" Executable="nodejs/node.exe">
          <desktop:FullTrustProcess>
            <desktop:ParameterGroup GroupId="SyncGroup" Parameters="/new1.js"/>
            <desktop:ParameterGroup GroupId="OtherGroup" Parameters="/Other"/>
          </desktop:FullTrustProcess>
        </desktop:Extension>
      </Extensions>
```

However, when I run the UWP app, the node.exe just appear for a second and immediately crashed. However when I call other applications like notepad++.exe, it will be open successfully. I'm wondering why this happened. Should I use FullTrustProcessLauncher or some other way to call nodejs(node.exe)? Looking forward to your help. Thanks.

Comment: did you try to look the node logs?

Comment: emmn, how to see that?

Comment: the node window just appear for a second, I don't have chance to see the log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have know the problem. With the FullTrustProcoessLauncher you can only launch an EXE that is in your package, not an arbitrary process on the system. I made another win32 process in my package and call nodejs in the win32 process. The problem is sovled now.

Answer (score 1):

The EXE needs to be included in the appx package

Then you should declare in the appx.manifest.

Make sure you declear the 'runFullTrust' capability in the appxmanifest.

You should have look the [FullTrustProcessLauncher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustProcessLauncher) ms docs.

Comment: I have declared the 'runFullTrust' capability and actually the exe can be called, it just disappear at once. I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Can you provide more error details? You should see the error details in Event Viewer

Comment: it didn't show any error, but the node.exe just exit, like a thread run over.

Comment: do you speak chinese?